# Could certain drugs enable one to consistently eat above TDEE or BMR without fat gains?

Tags: human-biology, metabolism, pharmacology, endocrinology, fat-metabolism

I heard anabolic steroids and stuff like DNP and ephedrine and etc. can somewhat enable one to eat more and get away with it without much or any fat gain, despite eating more than the body would normally use.

Is this true? Can hormones, AAS, HGH and other fat burning drugs or stimulants or etc. enable one to consistently eat more than their basal metabolic rate without becoming fat?

Comment: Do you remember where you heard this